# Boost.Test application debugging

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, boost

When debugging a C++ Boost.Test application inside VS2010 (VS2008), how to make the debugger stop at Boost.Test assertion failure points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but in theory you'd want to set a breakpoint somewhere in the [check_impl function](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/test/impl/test_tools.ipp) (in the boost_unit_test_library source), probably in the non-PASS cases of its final case statement.

In practice I always just find myself just running the tests again (or the specific problem test, selected with --run_test=...) with a breakpoint on the offending check.

Note that a failing `BOOST_REQUIRE` results in a throw, so if you enable VS' break-on-C++-exceptions in the debugging options that'll break on those nicely (but not `BOOST_CHECK`s, which just return and carry on).

Comment: Thank you. I also found it useful to follow procedure described in "Microsoft Visual Studio .NET users specific " chapter of the Boost.Test documentation. It permits to set a breakpoint manually at place where a verification is failing.

Answer (score 2):

I put breakpoints in `check_impl()`, as suggested by @timday.

Here is an extract from Boost 1.57.0, file `boost/test/impl/test_tool.ipp`, lines 355 to 373:

```
switch( tl ) {
case PASS:
    framework::assertion_result( true );
    return true;

case WARN:
    return false; // ADD BREAKPOINT HERE

case CHECK:
    framework::assertion_result( false );
    return false; // ADD BREAKPOINT HERE

case REQUIRE:
    framework::assertion_result( false );

    framework::test_unit_aborted( framework::current_test_case() );

    throw execution_aborted(); // ADD BREAKPOINT HERE
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in boost 1.63. The reporting of errors in test_tool.ipp seems to occur in a separate thread, or somehow at the end, when all tests were already checked. I would like to halt when the assertion occurs instead.

Answer (score 0):

assertion.hpp

template class binary_expr:

```
assertion_result            evaluate( bool no_message = false ) const
    {
        assertion_result const expr_res( value() );
        if( no_message || expr_res )
            return expr_res;   <<<<<<<<  SUCCESS

BRK        wrap_stringstream buff;
        report( buff.stream() );

        return tt_detail::format_assertion_result( buff.stream().str(), expr_res.message() );
    }
```